# Swift capture Live Photo

Tags: ios, swift, avcapturesession, phlivephoto

I'm trying to capture a Live Photo. I have followed Apples article on how to do this..

[Capturing and Saving Live Photos](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/capturing_still_and_live_photos/capturing_and_saving_live_photos)

However I am running into an issue regarding..

```
photoOutput?.isLivePhotoCaptureEnabled = photoOutput!.isLivePhotoCaptureSupported
```

It keeps returning `False`

I am running on an iPhone 7 that I can see is capable of taking Live Photos.

Anybody know why this Bool is not True?

Thanks.

Comment: Wild guess: make sure access to the camera is allowed for your app

Comment: Yes, I am already able to take photos..

Answer (score 2):

Before getting value of `isLivePhotoCaptureSupported`, you must setting  `captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo`. As follow:

```
captureSession.beginConfiguration()
captureSession.sessionPreset = .photo
// add Input
// add Output
photoOutput.isLivePhotoCaptureEnabled = photoOutput.isLivePhotoCaptureSupported
// ......
captureSession.commitConfiguration()
// ......
```